# Sed to search and replace pattern 1 which occurs before pattern 2

Tags: sed

I have file which contain data like below

```
Create table (
col1 int,
col2 string,
Primary key (Col1,
col2)
)
```

I want to comment `Primary` line and remove `,` which occurs before keyword `primary`. and I want to Add multi line comment till end of primary key definition

Output:

```
Create table (
col1 int,
col2 string
#Primary key (Col1,
#col2)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 'N;s/, *\n *Primary/\n#Primary/' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `N`: adds next line to the pattern space
- `s/, *\n *Primary/\n#Primary/`: removes trailing `,` from first line of the pattern space and replace `Primary` with `#Primary` in second line

Comment: But i am not sure if there is \n between last two brackets. I need \n after ')' which occurs only after 'PRIMARY' keyword how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This works. Preserving captured groups allows to re-inject linefeed.

```
$ sed 'N;s/, *\(\n\)\(Primary key\)/\1#\2/' input.txt
Create table (
col1 int,
col2 string
#Primary key (Col1)
)
```